# reading a text file with python return nothing

Tags: python

I have a text file with some content, I need to return that content in order to print it and some update
I used the absolute path to be sure the path is correct

```
file = open(r'path\to\file.txt','r')
```

This `print(file.read())` works fine, it returns the whole content. But when i try to return the content in a form of list using `print(file.readlines())` , it returns nothing; an empty list [].

my debugging was like this, I tried `len(file.readlines())` to make sure, it is indeed returning nothing, and it does. It prints 0

Comment: Is the `print(file.read())` line still in place before your call to `print(file.readlines())`?

Comment: Could you list all *steps* and show us how you do those steps?

Comment: @motto it is before

Comment: As @Ayb009 has pointed out, once you've read the file you have to reset the file position before you can read it again. If you remove the `print(file.read())` then the `readlines()` call will return lines.

Comment: Typically, if you want to read the entire file into memory, you'll save a reference to the contents and close the file. `with open(...) as file: contents = file.read()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key here is file **pointer**
`file.read()` after reading the content it sets the **pointer** at the end of your content.

- *solution 1(bad practice)* : open and close after every action `file.close()` then `opren(r'path\to\file.txt','r')`
- *solution 2*: change the file pointer

  `file.seek(0)` # 0 will set the pointer at the start,then use `print((file.readlines()))`

Comment: What does the mouse cursor have to do with reading from a file?

Comment: now it return a list of lines, thank you

Comment: @chepner i don't quite remember where, but i read it somewhere. it is not true i guess!

Answer (score -1):

So it should look something like this::

```
filename = "this/is/a/file"

with open(filename, "r") as file:
   lines_list = file.read_lines()

print(lines_list)
```

Just in case you don't know, you don't need to manually close the file when you use *with*. So that's why it's missing above.

Also, based on Ayb009's answer it just seems like you tried to read again without closing the file which would start from the last character read + 1. The solution here skips that issue entirely by letting you do whatever you want with the lines without needing to keep the file open.